# Camtasia video with machine narrator

Tags: voice, camtasia

I am new to Camtasia. Now I need to use machine narrator as the audio input instead of  microphone when I record on-screen activities, I didn't find out any solution for this case. Does any of you have any idea to integrate machine narrator into camtasia video? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is a Q/A site for programmers. If you'd like, you can ask at http://feedback.techsmith.com/techsmith.
It is TechSmith's general support forum. TechSmith is the creator of Camtasia. If you choose to ask there, elaborate on "Machine Narrator," because I genuinely don't understand. Good luck!